# Mongodb Aggregation pipeline performance issue after lookup stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I tried to run a query on huge data set but after lookup stage(stage 3) it took too much amount of time (approximately 12 hour) . How do I improve query performance . I am using single node with 16 cpu, 64 gb RAM with mongodb 4.0 version .

```
// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $match: {
         "ID" : "XXXXX"
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $redact: {
           $cond: [ { $or: [ { $eq: [ "$Masterid", "" ] }, { $or: [ { $eq: [ "$VKORG", "" ] }, { $or: [ { $eq: [ "$VTWEG", "" ] },{ $eq: [ "$UDATE", "" ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] }, "$$PRUNE", "$$KEEP" ] 
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "BU07-02", let: { raw_Masterid: "$Masterid", raw_VKORG: "$VKORG", raw_VTWEG: "$VTWEG", raw_SPART: "$SPART", raw_KUNNR: "$KUNNR",
               raw_VBELN: "$VBELN", raw_POSNR: "$POSNR", raw_UDATE: "$UDATE", raw_KNUMH: "$KNUMH", raw_AUART: "$AUART", raw_FKART: "$FKART",
                }, pipeline: [ { $match: { $expr: { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$raw_Masterid", "$Masterid" ] }, 
                  { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$raw_VKORG", "$VKORG" ] }, { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$raw_VTWEG", "$VTWEG" ] }, { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$raw_SPART", "$SPART" ] },
                     { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$raw_KUNNR", "$KUNNR" ] }, { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$raw_VBELN", "$AUBEL" ] }, { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$raw_POSNR", "$AUPOS" ] }, 
                       { $lte: [ "$$raw_UDATE", "$UDATE" ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } } } ], as: "BU07-02"
        }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$BU07-02",

        }
    },

    // Stage 5
    {
        $redact: {
        $cond: [ { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$Masterid", "$BU07-02.Masterid" ] }, { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$VKORG", "$BU07-02.VKORG" ] }, { $and: [ { $eq:
           [ "$VTWEG", "$BU07-02.VTWEG" ] }, { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$SPART", "$BU07-02.SPART" ] }, { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$KUNNR", "$BU07-02.KUNNR" ] }, 

                     { $and: [ { $ne: [ "$BU07-02.FKART", "ZBS1" ] },
                              { $and: [ { $ne: [ "$BU07-02.FKART", "ZBS2" ] }, { $and: [ { $ne: [ "$VBTYP", "U" ] }, { $and: [ { $ne: [ "$BU07-02.VBTYP", "U" ] }, 
                                { $ne: [ "$BASE_ENTITY", true ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] }, "$$KEEP", 
                                "$$PRUNE" ] }
    },      
],
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Neither the pipeline form of `$lookup` nor the `$expr` operator are able to make efficient use of an index.  This means that the `$lookup` stage is essentially reading every document in the `BU07-02` collection from disk in order to evaluate the all of the criteria.

You might try selecting the criteria that you expect will usually return the fewest documents and use it in a `foreignField` form of `$lookup`, making sure there is an index on that field in the `BU07-02`, and then apply the remaining criteria use a `$match` or `$filter`.